# Can't install or change package versions

Tags: installation, pip, package

I'm still learning things when it comes to Python, but I've hit with an issue that I cannot seem to resolve. So I've been trying to run a new script that a colleague prepared. However, when I try and run it, I got the following message:

'No module named pandas.util.testing'

I am assuming that my version of pandas is therefore not the right version for this script if I'm getting this message?
I checked my version of pandas (2.0.0) and it different to other colleagues for which the code works(they had 1.0.5).
I therefore uninstalled pandas using pip, but whenever I try and reinstall pandas version 1.0.5 (pip install pandas), I get the following:

'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:..'

I've had similar problems with other projects too, where I try and reinstall packages of different versions, but all I get is error messages.

Any help or advice that can get me into a position where I can install packages without absolute grief would be hugely appreciated.

I ran a script, but I get the following error message: 'No module named pandas.util.testing'

I tried 'pip install pandas==1.05'
I get the following error message: 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:..'